# Sed syntax difference MacOS vs GNU

Tags: bash, unix, sed, sh

I have the following piece of code that works perfectly on MacOS, but doesn't work on GNU (I'm using MinGW):

```
filename=$1
iter_count=$((${#src_op_lst[@]} -1))
for i in $(eval echo "{0..$iter_count}");do
    echo "Checking File :" $filename
    sed -i "" "s/[[:<:]]"${src_op_lst[$i]}"[[:>:]]/"${tgt_op_lst[$i]}"/g" $filename
done
```

I guess the reason is that `sed` syntax is differ, but I have no idea how to make it work on GNU. I've tried to use `sed -i -e ...`, but sed gives me following error: `-e expression #1, char 50: Invalid character class name`.

I'm very new to bash scripting, excuse me if this question is stupid. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]` are the problematic tokens. What were you trying to do here? They are parsed as a named character class, as would be for instance `[[:alnum:]]`, the class of the alphanumeric characters

Comment: ```[[:<:]]``` is indeed invalid char class name. What you trying to do with ```it```?

Comment: @Aaron @vgersh99 This script replaces all values from `src_op_lst` found in `filename` with corresponding values in `tgt_op_lst `

Comment: @Vladyslav what does the sample (couple of lines) from ```$filename``` look like?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `[[:<:]]` so I can only provide an educated guess : I think those might be word boundaries making sure you're matching a whole word rather than part of one. To replicate this with GNU sed you would want to use `\b` instead of both `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

Comment: Looks like my guess was correct : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393968/139867. I'll post an answer

Comment: Side notes : you can remove the `""` after `-i`, while its absence will raise incomprehensible errors on MacOS it's quite common in GNU sed and maintainers might wonder what the quotes are there for. I would also revise your quoting style, currently a space in one of the `src_op_lst` would break the sed command. I'd go with `"s/\b${src_op_lst[$i]}\b/${tgt_op_lst[$i]}/g"`. The `$filename` should also be double-quoted, otherwise you'll have surprises if you need to handle filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: Oh and if you don't know it, [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net/) is a great tool to help you pinpoint problems and bad practices in scripts.

Comment: Please don't use `eval` just to evaluate a dynamic brace expression. Just use the C-style for loop `for ((i=0; i< ${#src_op_list[@]}; i++))`. You can probably even get away with `for i in {!src_op_lst[@]}; do`, assuming your array isn't sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are tokens that MacOS's `sed` inteprets as directional word-boundaries : the first one lets you check you're matching at the start of a word and the second at the end of a word.
Those let you make sure you're replacing whole words rather than parts of words (e.g. avoiding to change `professor` into `confessor` when you're trying to replace `pro` with `con`).

The exact equivalent in GNU sed would be `\<` and `\>`.

However, as someone familiar with regex but not necessarily with the bazillion different implementations, I would suggest you use the more common `\b` instead of both `\<` and `\>`.
It's a direction-less word boundary which will match if you're either at the start or the end of a word. It will produce the exact same result in your case (and in most cases) and future maintainers will be more likely to be familiar with it and not go through the struggle you just experienced.

Comment: Thank you for help, this solution is working for me!