# Unable to use sed on Mac for exact match

Tags: bash, sed

I need to use replace a file checking exact matches of the word he or "he" but not replacing 'he' inside weather so I decided to use the sed command on macOS. I tries using both double quotes and single quotes but it doesn't change anything

```
sed 's/\<he\>/it/g' file-he.yaml > file-it.yaml
```

This is the Input file file-he.yaml.

```
name: "QBERT Utterance Understanding Search Plus Siri he"

  topics:
    
    - weatherEvent
    - he

environment_variables:
  LANG: "he"
```

The expected output is

```
name: "QBERT Utterance Understanding Search Plus Siri it"
    
      topics:
        
        - weatherEvent
        - it
    
    environment_variables:
      LANG: "it"
```

I also tried:

```
sed 's/"he"/it/g' file-he.yaml > file-it.yaml
```

which replaces even the occurrences of 'he' in weather. Any idea why that is?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502449/sed-syntax-difference-macos-vs-gnu

Comment: please update the question to include the expected output after running the replacement against your file (`file-he.yaml`)

Comment: Added the expected output @markp-fuso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've asked sed to match is `<he>` - so of course it doesn't update (that's because OSX sed isn't GNU sed).

If you want to replace `he` on it's own or `"he"` you'll need to match quite a few different cases (to make this work generally and not grab a `he` in a word).

- `\she\s*$`                  ie. Line ends with he
- `^\s*he\s`                  ie. Line starts with he
- `\she\s`                    ie. A he as a separate word
- `"he"`                      ie. "he"

Someone else suggested use `[[:<:]]` character class instead of `\<` - that works nicely on OSX ...

```
# ( echo "Cd    "; echo "       Cd"; echo "ABCdFg CdFg Cd \"Cd\""; echo "Ab Cd EfG") | \
sed -e 's/[[:<:]]Cd[[:>:]]/FOO/g'
FOO    
       FOO
ABCdFg CdFg FOO "FOO"
AB'FOO
Ab FOO EfG
```